# iptables not catching packets based on source IP

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, ip

I'm creating a proxy server on `Debian` 8, and are trying to do `DNAT` on incoming packets - which are being forwarded from another server.

This is my `iptables` `DNAT` rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.1.10.10/10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3 --persistent
```

However, no packets are being detected and send to `192.168.2.3`.
In `wireshark` I see a lot of incoming packets with source IP `10.1.10.76`, but they do not get a new destination IP.

As my server is a `proxy` I do not have an `interface` with source IPs `10.1.10.10/10`, so I'm thinking if iptables is not listening on for all packets.

UPDATE

It seems the nat rule are being hit, but destination IP is not changed:

```
Every 2.0s: iptables -nvL -t nat                                                              Mon Jun 18 10:36:39 2018

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1647 packets, 75652 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  285 18890 DNAT       all  --  *      *       10.1.10.10/10       ! 10.1.10.10/10        to: 192.168.2.3 persistent
```

I've only got `eth0` and `eth1` with a single private and single public IP attached to it.
`ip route list` only contains `default via 192.168.2.255`.

Comment: You did set the kernel tuneable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` which is required to allow packet forwarding?

Comment: Yes, `net.ipv4.ip_forward` = 1.

Comment: And it seems the rule are being hit (see update)

Comment: Add your interfaces info to the question, `ip addr show` and `ip route show`.

Comment: Adding `iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.2.3 -j ACCEPT ` makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.2.3 -j ACCEPT
```

makes it work.
Apparently need to allow the forwarding of packets.

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

to allow all DNATed packets through which usually is what you want when you start playing with NAT.

See `man iptables-extensions` for more details.